# How to encrypt and save a binary stream after serialization and read it back?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, cryptography

I am having some problems in using CryptoStream when I want to encrypt a binary stream after binary serialization and save it to a file. I am getting the following exception

```
System.ArgumentException : Stream was not readable.
```

Can anybody please show me how to encrypt a binary stream and save it to a file and deserialize it back correctly?

The code is as follows:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b = new B {Name = "BB"};
            WriteFile<B>(@"C:\test.bin", b, true);
            var bb = ReadFile<B>(@"C:\test.bin", true);

            Console.WriteLine(b.Name == bb.Name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static T ReadFile<T>(string file, bool decrypt)
        {
            T bObj = default(T);
            var _binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream buffer = null;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                if(decrypt)
                {
                    const string strEncrypt = "*#4$%^.++q~!cfr0(_!#$@$!&#&#*&@(7cy9rn8r265&$@&*E^184t44tq2cr9o3r6329";
                    byte[] dv = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF};
                    CryptoStream cs;
                    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = null;

                    var byKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strEncrypt.Substring(0, 8));
                    using (des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
                    {
                        cs = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(byKey, dv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                    }
                    buffer = cs;
                }
                else
                    buffer = stream;
                try
                {
                    bObj = (T) _binaryFormatter.Deserialize(buffer);
                }
                catch(SerializationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            return bObj;
        }

        public static void WriteFile<T>(string file, T bObj, bool encrypt)
        {
            var _binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream buffer;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
                try
                {
                    if(encrypt)
                    {
                        const string strEncrypt = "*#4$%^.++q~!cfr0(_!#$@$!&#&#*&@(7cy9rn8r265&$@&*E^184t44tq2cr9o3r6329";
                        byte[] dv = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF};
                        CryptoStream cs;
                        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = null;

                        var byKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strEncrypt.Substring(0, 8));
                        using (des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
                        {
                            cs = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(byKey, dv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                            buffer = cs;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        buffer = stream;

                    _binaryFormatter.Serialize(buffer, bObj);
                    buffer.Flush();
                }
                catch(SerializationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class B
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }
```

It throws the serialization exception as follows

The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes)
are: 3F-17-2E-20-80-56-A3-2A-46-63-22-C4-49-56-22-B4-DA ...

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the CryptoStreams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do it like this, it should work:

```
// A: encrypting when writing
// 1. create backing storage stream. In your case a file stream
using(Stream innerStream = File.Create(path))
// 2. create a CryptoStream in write mode
using(Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(innerStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    // 3. write to the cryptoStream
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, obj);
}

// B: decrypting when reading
// 1. create backing storage stream. In your case a file stream
using(Stream innerStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
// 2. create a CryptoStream in read mode
using(Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(innerStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    // 3. read from the cryptoStream
    obj = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
}
```

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You're using an encryptor when reading. This was probably a typo, but it should be a decryptor.
2. You are flushing the `buffer`, but that is not enough when using a `CryptoStream`. Encryptors and decryptors work on blocks of a fixed size. The last block may not have that size, so it needs special treatment. The last block is the one written before the stream is *closed*, not *flushed*. Flushing on a CryptoStream does nothing useful, because it cannot write anything of size less than the  input block size of the encryptor/decryptor, unless it is the last thing to be written. And on top of this, in general you should always close your streams, no matter what. The `using` statement is the recommended way of doing it:

   ```
   using(buffer)
       _binaryFormatter.Serialize(buffer, bObj);
   ```

Comment: Serialization is working but not the deserialization. The error details is as follows:

System.ArgumentException : Stream was not readable.
   at System.IO.BinaryReader..ctor(Stream input, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser..ctor(Stream stream, ObjectReader objectReader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at ..

Comment: What are you using as the innerStream? The same stream you used for serialization? You need a stream that can be read from. And, if you wrote to it previously, you'll need to "rewind" it back to the beginning. If it is seekable `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` should do the trick. If it isn't seekable, you'll probably need to open it again.

Comment: I tried it, but this time it gives serialization exception saying

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 3F-17-2E-20-80-56-A3-2A-46-63-22-C4-49-56-22-B4-2E ...

Comment: @Anindya: ok, you'll have to show us your code. There is a limit to the amount of psychic debugging one can do.

Comment: @Anindya: Can you serialize and deserialize a different object, like say a GUID or a string?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. It was a part of a big code. I had to strip it down and I have updated the main question with the relevant part. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @Anindya: I looked at your code and found the problem. Try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great example on how to do this in the MSDN documentation:
[CryptoStream MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx)  it's in the "Examples" section.

The procedure is basically this:

1. create cryptostream (empty stream)
2. write contents to cryptostream (encrypt)
3. save cryptostream to file
4. create cryptostream from file contents
5. read from cryptostream (decrypt)

Comment: Problem arises at step 2. and step 6. as I am not writing string data to the file. I want to encrypt an already created binary stream and deserialize from a crypto stream. These things freaking me out!!!

Comment: @Anindya Chatterjee   2.A byte array can be written ,  deserializing into an object would be done by reading everything in the cryptostream (byte array output)