# VB.NET: Save & load data?

Tags: vb.net, file, loading, save

Let's say I got a Dictionary type object holding some important info.
Well, my user wants to close the program and work on it later.

How do I save the Dictionary and other variables in one single file, which can only be read by my program itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for simple, I have two words for you: [**binary serialization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b.aspx).

The serialization capabilities built into the .NET Framework are awesome for tasks like this, where you just want to spit some of your program's instance data out to disk without worrying about writing a bunch of code yourself.

Since you're not worried about adhering to any kind of an open or standard data format, there's no benefit to XML serialization. Just choose a custom file extension to use for your application (preferably one that's not already in use by very many others—remember you don't necessarily have to limit yourself to just 3 characters), and then associate that file extension with your application in the Windows shell.

Of course, this won't do anything to *encrypt* the data. Someone could still open up your data file in Notepad and see its contents, but they won't be very pretty. It's not a human-readable data format, but it's not necessarily secure either. Your question is ambiguous on whether or not this is required.

**EDIT:** I see you've added in a comment that you'd prefer to be able to encrypt your data. No problem. The accepted answer to this question suggests a way to do that in conjunction with binary serialization: [How to encrypt and save a binary stream after serialization and read it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584135/how-to-encrypt-and-save-a-binary-stream-after-serialization-and-read-it-back) Essentially, you'll want to use the [`CryptoStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) to handle the encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 1):

There are about a million and one ways to do this.  A lot depends on what you want and how far you want to go.  The key piece here is "only read by my program".  More than likely you will need to come up with some file format, or encryption mechanism if you don't want others to read it.

Comment: I'd like to make my own file format for this application (and an encryption mechanism), can you guide me about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only talking about a relatively small amount of data, it is probably easy to just serialize it to XML.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize.aspx

Basically, you give the serializer an object, and it will take all of its properties and what and convert them to XML.

From there, you can encrypt it (see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx) and write it to a file.

Be careful though.  .NET programs are easily disassembled, and your encryption key can be found.